# Ansible variable is defined, yet default filter still gets processed

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Take this bit of code:

```yaml
- name: One
  set_fact:
    test_var: "default_name"

- name: Two
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test_var is defined }}"
  
- name: Three
  set_fact:
    second_test_var: '{{ test_var | default(groups | my_custom_filter_plugin("should not execute")) }}'
```

The filter plugin looks like this:

```py
def my_custom_filter_plugin(groups, txt):
    print(groups)
    return "Test"


class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Testing filters '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'my_custom_filter_plugin': my_custom_filter_plugin
        }
```

From this text I read that defaults only get executed if a variable is not defined: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values

My variable is defined... and yet the code in the default filter gets executed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: In the above scenario, the code inside the default is always executed. The resulting value of the full expression will be evaluated. if your variable is defined, you get the value of the variable else the default which needs to exist prior to evaluating the full expression. This is how jinja works. To get an other confirmation try the following: `'{{ test_var | default(undefined_var) }}'` <= you will get an error because `undefined_var` does not exist even though `test_var` is defined.

Comment: @Zeitounator So even if the use case of the code is "only do this if the first variable is undefined", it still requires the entire statement be evaluated during execution... Ok then, if you put that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Zeitounator, your example is oddly not totally true. `'{{ test_var | default(undefined_var) }}'` somehow does not error. But as soon as you do `'{{ test_var | default(undefined_var | any_filter) }}'`, then it starts erroring.

Comment: It looks like the behavior is " If there's a pipe, evaluate the statement, regardless of further context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this taking an other route and use an [inline if](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if-expression) expression instead of the `default` filter.

So, your last `set_fact` would become:

```yaml
- name: Three
  set_fact:
    second_test_var: >-
      {{ 
        test_var 
          if test_var is defined 
          else groups | my_custom_filter_plugin("should not execute") 
      }}
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        second_test_var: >-
          {{ 
            test_var 
              if test_var is defined 
              else I_do_not_exists | int 
          }}
      vars: 
        test_var: foobar

    - debug:
        var: second_test_var

    - name: Showing that doing the same with `default` errors
      set_fact:
        second_test_var: "{{ test_var | default(I_do_not_exists | int) }}"
      vars: 
        test_var: foobar
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  second_test_var: foobar

TASK [Showing that doing the same with `default` errors] ************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'I_do_not_exists' is undefined
  
    The error appears to be in '/usr/local/ansible/play.yml': line 18, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
  
        - name: Showing that doing the same with `default` errors
          ^ here
```